# Iterating through alphabet and get newly created strings back to their original Button Form

Tags: c#, iteration

After a long search I finally found the winning strategy to clean up some code on my hangman game, but an explanation is needed so I understand.

When the game opens, I originally wanted all the letter buttons to be disabled. So I created a method to do just that,

```
private void disableletters();
{
  A.Enabled = false;
  B.Enabled = false;
         .
         .
         .
  Z.Enabled = false;
}
```

Effective but not very elegant. So iterating through the alphabet to try and condense this code seemed logical.

```
private void disableLetters()
{
  char alphebetStart = Char.Parse("A");
  char alphabetEnd = Char.Parse("Z");

  for (i = alphabetStart; i <= alphabetEnd; i++);
  {
    string allLetters = i.ToString();
  }
}
```

But the challenge appeared to be just starting because I couldn't use these newly created strings as Button Forms like this,

```
i.ToString().Enabled = false;
```

for obvious reasons. They were strings but they needed to be understood as their original form.

The long search finally revealed a solution, but I don't really understand quite what it's doing. The magic was,

```
Controls[allLetters].Enabled = false;
```

The "Controls" reveals something cryptic, "Gets the collection of controls contained within the control." The code works as planned, but it looks like what it's doing is saying, "Take those new strings you created A thru Z and understand them as what they were originally as the name of the buttons."

If someone could briefly explain what this code is doing, I'd be grateful.

Comment: to get a `char` variable starting at `A` you can just use `'A'` rather than `char.Parse("A")`.  Single quotes are used to define character literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final code is in no way related to your variables.  While there is a variable `A` that represents a control, there is also an entirely separate collection within the form that has all of the `Control` objects within it.  Each of those control object has a `Name` field, and one of them has a string value of `"A"`.  You can find the object in that collection with a name value of `"A"` easily enough.  That there happens to be a variable called `A` that references that control is (from the point of view of the computer) a coincidence.  If you renamed the variable (but didn't change the name of the control) to something like `"A1"`, then you'd still need to use `"A"` to get the control using the `Controls` collection.

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ, you could also have done something like...

```
// where alphabet is a List<Char>
alphabet.ForEach(c => this.Controls[c].Enabled = false);
```

Comment: Actually, on second thought, alphabet would probably work if it was a plain old string like `"ABCD....XYZ"`.